# Magento 2.1.3 adding menu.xml in new module causes redirect loop after login

Tags: redirect, magento-2.1.3, adminmenu

Adding menu.xml in a new magento 2.1.3 installation causes redirect loop in the admin

I am creating a new module, but when tried to add menu.xml in etc/adminhtml directory in the module directiory, the browser shows error of redirect loop
Magento Version: Magento CE 2.1.3
Mysql Version:  5.6.28
PHP version: 7.0.8

Steps to reproduce issue
1. Install new Magento CE 2.1.3 
2. Create new module in app/code with all required files in etc directory of the module
3. Add menu.xml and add items in the menu

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Ktpl_Testimonial::menu" title="IntroBrand" translate="title" module="Ktpl_Testimonial" sortOrder="0" resource="Ktpl_Testimonial::menu"/>
        <add id="Ktpl_Testimonial::testimonial" title="Manage Testimonials" translate="title" module="Ktpl_Testimonial" sortOrder="0" parent="Ktpl_Testimonial::menu" resource="Ktpl_Testimonial::testimonial"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**Edit**

Added acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Ktpl_Testimonial::menu">
                    <resource id="Ktpl_Testimonial::testimonial"/>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

#### Expected result

It should add a main menu item in the admin menu and a child menu item in the new menu item.

#### Actual result

It creates a redirect loop when try to log in to the admin

[image: screenshot from 2017-01-19 12 44 34]

Comment: have you enable module Ktpl_IntroBrand?

Comment: Might be issue in resource Ktpl_IntroBrand

Comment: Yes, i have enabled the module rakesh.

Comment: I have added the acl.xml

Comment: Try with         <add id="Ktpl_Testimonial::testimonial" title="Manage Testimonials" translate="title" module="Ktpl_Testimonial" sortOrder="0" parent="Ktpl_Testimonial::menu" resource="Ktpl_Testimonial::testimonial"/>

Comment: Oh, sorry, mybad, Let me edit the question, but that does not change anything.

Comment: did you try to flush `var/cache` and `var/generation` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set resource of root item to `Magento_Backend::content`